# How to read content json files in another folder in Symfony

Tags: javascript, json, symfony

In my JS file I want to get content to my json file

```
/src 
     /Resources
          /public
                 /js 
                       main.js
                 /json
                       file.json
```

E.g to my `main.js`. When I try this, it doesn't work.

```
$.get("../json/file.json", function(){...})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your `Resources` directory is inside a bundle the `assets:install` command has been run, use this one:

```
$.get("/bundles/[bundle_name]/json/files.json", function() {
    // ...
});
```

Where `[bundle_name]` is the name of your bundle lowercased and uncamelized (underscores), e.g. for a bundle with location `src/AcmeBundle`, `[bundle_name]` is `acme`.